# Setting markers fro scatter plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I wanted to set markers for scatter plot as shown below[image]

I am using matplotlib library for plotting until now I am able to plot only the points by the code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
x = [39.5,38,42.5]
y = np.array([0,1,2])
my_xticks = ['a','b','c']
plt.yticks(y, my_xticks)
plt.scatter(x, y,marker='x',s=100)

plt.show()
```

I also want the line as shown in figure above as a marker in my plot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do this would be to call `plt.hlines`, so that you can add a few horizontal lines to your markers.

Example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
x = np.array([39.5,38,42.5])
y = np.array([0,1,2])
my_xticks = ['a','b','c']
plt.yticks(y, my_xticks)
plt.scatter(x, y,marker='x',s=100)
width = .4
plt.hlines(y, xmin=x - width/2, xmax=x + width/2)
plt.show()
```

Change `width` to suit your desired "width" for each line. Colors can be changed as well, check the documentation for [plt.hlines](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.hlines).

Note that this will not persist in a call to `legend`. `legend` will only use the actual line objects, although there are ways to change that too.